# Solution to Homogeneous Euler Equation with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to have Mathematica provide the solution to the classic Euler equation:
$$
J\dot{\omega}+\omega^\times J\omega=0
$$
I have assumed that $J$ is diagonal.
It should provide three solutions, two specular solutions with the Jacobi functions.
Instead, it won't find anything by trying with DSolve:

```
DSolve[{-J2 omega2[t] omega3[t]+J3 omega2[t] omega3[t]+J1 D[omega1[t],t]==0,J1 omega1[t] omega3[t]-J3 omega1[t] omega3[t]+J2 D[omega2[t],t]==0,-J1 omega1[t] omega2[t]+J2 omega1[t] omega2[t]+J3 D[omega3[t],t]==0,
             omega1[0]==0,omega2[0]==0,omega3[0]==A},{omega1,omega2,omega3},t]
```

Comment: **t won't find anything by trying with DSolve** in V 14 it solves them. But lots of warning messages.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9xol.png)  make sure your input and IC are correct if this is not the solution expected.

Comment: Even by setting omega2[0]==B, it won't find a solution. Plus why all those warning messages? This should be a well known solution.

Comment: why do you mean by **it won't find a solution**? did you see the screen shot I posted? These are solutions. If this is not the solution you expect, may be the input you posted need to be changed or maybe Mathematica did not obtain the correct solution. But solutions are obtained. Can you show screen shot of your input/out?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics).   J is a body fixed symmetric tensor,  rotating in space,  while $\vec \omega$is a vector in the non rotating space  rest system. The ingenious Euler equations relate differences of ratios of the eiegenvalues $$(J_1-J_2)\omega_1 \omega_2 = J_3 \dot \omega_3$$ cyclic, that cannot digonalized

Comment: Yes, I corrected my post, there was a typo...

Comment: with your correction, yes, now DSolve gives no solution. Are you sure a solution exist for this system of odes's? It can solve it, but not for the IC conditions you give. So I think your IC might have issue. V 14 gives solution in terms of JacobiSN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution without explicit initial condition is obtained by:

```
inert = DiagonalMatrix[{J1, J2, J3}];
w = {w1[t], w2[t], w3[t]};
eq = inert . D[w, t] + Cross[w, inert . w] == {0, 0, 0};
DSolve[eq, w, t]
```

However, for an explicit example with initial conditions for a tumbling motion:

```
inert = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 3/4, 1/2}];
w = {w1[t], w2[t], w3[t]}; w0 = {1, 1, 2};
tmax = 100;
eq = {inert . D[w, t] + Cross[w, inert . w] == {0, 0, 
     0}, (w /. t -> 0 ) == w0};
sol = NDSolve[eq, w, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

wt = w /. sol;
ParametricPlot3D[wt, {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image]